# Keeping the scrollbar position of a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, scrollbar, postback

I have a little problem with my dynamically created controls. I have a asp.net page using c# code behind. I generated rows for a table (inside an update panel). In one of those rows,  I have a label created with content and a vertical scrollbar. I also have a timer calling a postback every 5 seconds.

```
Label diff = new Label();
diff.Style.Add("height", height + "px");
diff.Style.Add("width", "100%");
diff.BorderWidth = 2;
diff.Style.Add("overflow-y", "scroll");
diff.Text = text;
cell.Controls.Add(diff);
```

The problem is that when the postback occurs, the row is deleted and created again, so the scroll position is lost.

I would like to keep the scroll position in a variable to be able to set it to the same position after the postback. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think this scenario is a prime candidate for AJAX.

Comment: I use a little AJAX for my timer, but never used it before. Do you have a suggestion of what I might look for in AJAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin [`ScrollSaver`](http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scrollsaver.min.js"></script>
```

All you have to do is include the script on the page and before a Postback occurs it will save the location of each element in a cookie and then restore it when the page re-renders.

Comment: I downloaded the script and tried it. It keeps giving me an error when it refreshes (an unknown error, so the message doesn't help me), it may be because the label doesn't exist in the page when it refreshes, but is created in the timer_tick function.

Comment: @Amaranth: The error is unknown to you, but maybe not for someby else. So why not posting it? Try to assign always the same ID instead of none. "Just remember that only the scroll position of the elements which have their ID attribute set, can be maintained by this script!" http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver

Comment: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500". Each label already have a unique id and is always the same.

Comment: Ok, I found my problem and it works fine now. There was an illegal character in the id... Thanks for the help. However, there seem to be a small side effect. I reset some of my variables on the session_start, but this method seem to keep those variables in the cookie... Is there a way to clear only that cookie on session_start?

Comment: @Amaranth: You may want to ask another question since this issue is not related anymore to this question :)